# Is there a name for being obsessed with matte surfaces/objects/items?

Tags: preferences

*Apologies in advance if this isn't supposed to be here, I'm new, just let me know where to post it and I'll delete and post elsewhere!*

I was wondering if there's a condition or name or something along those lines for a person who is, for want of a better word, fascinated by matte surfaces/objects/items? My SO is drawn to them and we were just wondering if there's a name for it or if it's just a "thing" so to speak?

I've met a lot of people who enjoy different surface textures and so on but I've never met anyone as fascinated by matte surfaces as my SO is - he thoroughly enjoys rubbing/feeling my matte phone case, he always comments and complements when I wear a matte lipstick and he will always comment on how nice the finish is on something painted with matte paint to give you a few examples. If what has taken his attention (a case for something, my lipstick, a surface of any given type etc.) isn't matte, there is no comment from him.

I'm just curious to see if this is a thing or if it's just him.

Thanks in advance for any help!!

*Note this causes no problems or anything between us, it's literally just my curiosity has gotten the better of me and I couldn't find anything about it on Google. Also if anyone could point out what tags to use it would be much appreciated.*

Comment: Somewhat related: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/93640/why-do-we-prefer-shiny-finish-on-cars-and-dull-finish-on-devices and https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0042698913002782

Comment: And maybe https://www.quora.com/Do-people-with-high-functioning-autism-have-a-special-interest-in-the-feel-of-different-surfaces although I haven't seen any more scientific studies on that.

Comment: @Fizz thanks, I'll check those links out! No neither have I, just said I'd chance it and see if anyone knew anything, it's a strange world we live in after all!